# Change value of AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, autocompletetextview

I have a AutoCompleteTextView and in **setOnItemClickListener**  i want to check when user type an special text, AutoCompleteTextView clears and set to "". But when i do this an get an Stack Overflow Error. In general, every change in **setOnItemClickListener** generate Error!! i want to set some changes in my AutoCompleteTextView! How i can do this?

Comment: have you added a Text watcher to the AutocompleteTextview?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a  TextChangedListener instead of onItemListener

```
textView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, ....){
        //if "s" is your "special" text clear the textview
    }
});
```